# try, except через def. Не понятна логика

Tags: python, парсер

Учусь парсить. При парсинге не кажая страница содержит определённые строки. Отрабатываю исключение через try/except - получается. При добавлени обработки через def -не работает.

Выражение 1. Отрабатывает None строки отлично:

```
try:
    saller_rate = "https://www.farpost.ru/" + soup.find("a", class_="ratingPositive").get("href")

except:
    saller_rate = None
```

Выражение 2. Не отрабатывает и выдаёт ошибку.

```
 def test(vir):
  try:
        rez=vir
  except:
        rez=None
  return rez

 saller_rate_link = test("https://www.farpost.ru/" + soup.find("a", class_="ratingPositive").get("href"))
```

Ошибка:

```
saller_rate_link = test("https://www.farpost.ru/" + soup.find("a", class_="ratingPositive").get("href"))  # Ссылка на рейтинг продавца
```

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get'

Подскажите как правильно добавить обработку в функцию, т.к. стрко десятки и добавлять для каждую свою try/except сильно загромождает код.

Comment: Ооо, кто-то дром парсить пытается. Юзайте селениум. У них работают фанаты джаваскрипт

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот смотрите, вы написали вот так:

```py
foo(очень + длинное + выражение)
```

Возможно, вы думаете что тем самым вы передаёте `очень + длинное + выражение` как параметр функции `foo` - но это не совсем так. На всех современных языках программирования общего назначения вы не можете передать в качестве параметра выражение, передаётся всегда только вычисленное значение.

А это означает, что если при вычислении `очень + длинное + выражение` произойдёт ошибка - функция foo не будет вызвана, и потому никак не сможет эту ошибку обработать.

Что тут можно сделать? Ну, если ваша цель - проигнорировать любые ошибки, то можно воспользоваться лямбда-функциями. Превратив ваше выражение в лямбду, вы сможете передать его в функцию целиком и вызвать уже внутри:

```py
foo(lambda: очень + длинное + выражение)
```

Или, более конкретно:

```py
def test(expr):
  try:
    return expr()
  except:
    return None

saller_rate_link = test(labmda: …)
```

Но я бы не рекомендовал вам так делать. Делая так, вы игнорируете **любые** ошибки возникающие при вычислении, и теряете информацию о том какая ошибка произошла. Однажды ваша программа, будучи запущенной в неожиданных условиях, просто выдаст на выходе None - и вас будут ожидать часы и дни попыток узнать что именно там произошло.

Ожидаемые ситуации следует обрабатывать не через try/except - а прописывая явные проверки на этот случай. К примеру, если вы пытаетесь отловить ситуацию, когда метод find вернул None - ну так и проверьте именно этот случай:

```py
def get_saller_rate_link(soup):
  if (ratingPositiveLink := soup.find("a", class_="ratingPositive")) is None:
    return None

  return … + ratingPositiveLink.get("href") + …
```

Если же подобная ситуация ожидаемой не является - имеет смысл ловить её через try/except, но делать это надо не индивидуально для каждой строчки - а для крупных блоков. И, главное, надо не "проглатывать" исключение, а выводить его в консоль или лог-файл:

```py
import traceback

try:
    saller_rate_link = …
    another_link = …
    some_data = …
    another data = …
except Exception as e:
    traceback.print_exception(e)
```

Comment: Большое спасибо за ОЧЕНЬ развёрнутый и подробный ответ! Очень  пригодится в будущем!

Answer (score 1):

В функции `test(vir)` в блоке `try` вы просто присваиваете значение, оно никогда не перейдет к  `except`. Эта конструкция здесь бессмысленна.

`try-except` нужно применять к данной конструкции `soup.find("a", class_="ratingPositive").get("href")` т.к. именно она возвращает None, если ничего не находит, а конкатенация строки и `None` в результате дает `None`.